# st_transform fails with Postgres.app

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Not sure if I have a version problem, library problem, permission issues etc.

```
SELECT PostGIS_Full_Version();
POSTGIS="2.1.4 r12966" 
GEOS="3.4.2-CAPI-1.8.2 r3921" 
PROJ="Rel. 4.8.0, 6 March 2012" 
GDAL="GDAL 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24" 
LIBXML="2.9.1" 
LIBJSON="UNKNOWN" (core procs from "2.1.0 r11822" need upgrade) 
RASTER (raster procs from "2.1.0 r11822" need upgrade)
```

ST_Transform does not appear to work on rasters (at least for me). Non-raster objects can be ST_Transformed without any issue. *Is anyone else having problems with raster st_transform?*

Here is an example which in my environment generates the an error.

```
SELECT ST_Transform(
  ST_AsRaster(
   ST_GeomFromText(E'LINESTRING(100.495995129 13.7117836894,100.495962221169 13.7117761471941)',4326),
        100., -100.,
        ARRAY['8BUI', '8BUI', '8BUI', '8BUI']::text[],
        ARRAY[29, 194, 178, 255]::double precision[],
         ARRAY[0, 0, 0, 0]::double precision[]
           ) 
,32647);
ERROR:  rt_raster_gdal_warp: Could not create GDAL transformation object for output dataset creation
CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_transform" statement 1
```

This ST_Transform does work when using a portablegis install with postgres version 2.1.3 r12547 (under Windows 8.1 rather than Postgres.app on OS X).

Comment: I have solved my problem by adding the PROJSO environment variable 

do shell script "launchctl setenv PROJSO /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/lib/libproj.dylib"